# Replace xml tag along with value in xml request string

Tags: java, xml, spring, string

I want to replace following String in an xml request where ever it occurs (occurs multiple time)

```
<trade_qty><![CDATA[OLDQTY]]></trade_qty>
```

With

```
<trade_qty><![CDATA[NEWQTY]]></trade_qty>
```

Where I will be specifying the NEWQTY from my code

Similarly, I want to replace the LAST OCCURRENCE of following String

```
<fixed_price><![CDATA[OLDPRICE]]></fixed_price>
```

with

```
<fixed_price><![CDATA[NEWPRICE]]></fixed_price>
```

Where I will specifying the NEWPRICE from my code.

Please Help!

We can also skip the CDATA part if required, in the resultant string:

viz., `<fixed_price>NEWPRICE</fixed_price>` and `<trade_qty>NEWQTY</trade_qty>`

I tried this from ([https://www.logicbig.com/how-to/java-string/replace-between-two-strings.html](https://stackoverflow.com))
But it didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved using Jsoup

```
public String transformXML(String tradeDataXML, Double newQty, Double newPrice)
{
    String newXML = "";
    org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.parse(tradeDataXML, "", Parser.xmlParser());

    CDataNode trade_qty = (CDataNode) doc.selectFirst("SwapTermList trade_qty").childNode(0);
    CDataNode fixed_price = (CDataNode) doc.selectFirst("SwapTermList TermPriceList fixed_price").childNode(0);

    if(trade_qty != null && fixed_price != null) {
        logger.info("original values of trade_qty and fixed_price: " + trade_qty.text() + SPACE_AND_COMMA + fixed_price.text());
    }

    if(trade_qty != null) trade_qty.text((newQty == null)?"":newQty.toString());
    if(fixed_price != null) fixed_price.text((newPrice == null)?"":newPrice.toString());

    if(trade_qty != null && fixed_price != null) {
        logger.info("Replaced values of trade_qty and fixed_price: " + trade_qty.text() + SPACE_AND_COMMA + fixed_price.text());
    }

    doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);
    newXML = doc.outerHtml();
    return newXML;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using XSLT for this problem in Java is possible but gets awkward if your replacements differ for various input values. Using XPath and DOM-API is much easier.

Given an input XML document like this:

```
<container>
    <trade_qty><![CDATA[123]]></trade_qty>
    <trade_qty><![CDATA[234]]></trade_qty>
    <fixed_price><![CDATA[345.67]]></fixed_price>
    <fixed_price><![CDATA[456.78]]></fixed_price>
</container>
```

```
@Test
void testReplace() throws Exception {
    // Just for reading the source XML document
    var r = new DOMResult();
    try(InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/replace.xml")) {
        TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(new StreamSource(is), r);
    }
    
    Node doc = r.getNode(); // This is your XML document as a DOM-Node
    
    // REPLACEMENT BEGIN
    var xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath(); // We want to use XPath to find the ocurrences of trade_qty and fixed_price
    
    // Replace trade_qty ...
    var nodes = (NodeList)xPath.evaluate("container/trade_qty", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for(int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        nodes.item(i).setTextContent("100"); // Replace with new content.
    }
    // The same for container/fixed_price. Omitted for simplicity.
    
    // REPLACEMENT end
    
    // Just for checking the output
    try(ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(os));
        System.out.println(os.toString());
    }
}
```

Note that a CDATA section is just a representation for a text node in XML where you don't have to escape some special characters (e.g. < and &). Thus `<trade_qty><!CDATA[123]]></trade_qty>` and `<trade_qty>123</trade_qty>` are the same.

## Edit

Some useful XPaths:

1. `//trade_qty` selects any trade_qty element in your XML document.
2. `//TermPriceList/fixed_price` selects any fixed_price element that is a child of TermPriceList.

Comment: Thanks Karsten, will give it a go. In case of fixed_price, it comes in the xml multiple times, but I need to replace only the tag that comes under <TermPriceList>... </TermPriceList> tags. i.e., not all occurrences are to be replaced, What can be done in this case?

Comment: Since Rassermann receives the XML as a string, you probably want `new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml))` rather than using getResourceAsStream.  Simlarly, you may want to return the new XML using a StreamResult that wraps a StringWriter.

Comment: I made bad experiences putting XML documents into strings. I recommend using byte arrays or you will get encoding problems sometime.

Comment: See the edit. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks Everyone. This was solved using JSoup.

Answer (score 0):

It just needs a couple of lines of XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="trade_qty[.=$oldprice]">
  <xsl:copy>{$newprice}</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

where $oldprice and $newprice are parameters to the stylesheet.

I've used XSLT 3.0 syntax here for brevity but if you prefer to use an XSLT 1.0 processor it's perfectly feasible, just a bit more verbose.

Comment: THanks Michael. How to use it in Java? It is an existing xml that I get from some other program and I am supposed to either overwrite those 2 tags in specific places or overwrite value inside them with new value

Comment: There's a choice of XSLT processors available to the Java programmer. The one that's bundled with the JDK supports XSLT 1.0, and later versions are supported in third party libraries such as my own company's product Saxon. For an introduction to the API for executing XSLT from Java, see https://saxonica.com/documentation12/index.html#!using-xsl/embedding

Comment: Note, like most powerful technologies, XSLT does have a learning curve associated with it. But the benefits of doing XML transformations in XSLT rather than in low-level Java code are immense.

Comment: @MichaelKay I agree that XSLT is a powerful tool when dealing with XML. But in this case XSLT is like using a sledgehammer cracking a nut. Even the code for calling the XSLT with parameters exceeds the few lines using XPath directly. Another question is which implementation to use. XSLT 1.0 is for free use, 2+ implementations are either free but restricted in functionality or do cost lots of money.

Comment: Personally, I think that manipulating XML using DOM APIs is the sledgehammer. But of course everyone can have their own views, and it does depend on your project constraints.

Comment: THanks Everyone. This was solved using JSoup